# draft update with big Attachment by resumable upload return 404

Tags: gmail-api

my draft with big Attachment.

1. create draft with gapi.
2. update this draft add some big file.
3. upload draft rawdata by resumable upload.
4. when i start a resumable session, it return 404.

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/r3718017142990379914
    [method] => post
    [http_header] => Array
        (
            [0] => Authorization: Bearer ya29.****
            [1] => Content-type: application/json
            [2] => X-Upload-Content-Type: message/rfc822
        )
    [response] => HTTP/1.1 200 Tunnel established

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Up-CJW9XP4E84DqWjZhI_8-YFgWR47UNNfqGkmM2S5EBf3H5aGOcuwHzLd-4faoKAxd_qgaO5GInDUiJx6uua8JDwj4X0yLamxA--WySFB3ZZxw7YQ
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 12:48:24 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"

Not Found
    [res_header] => HTTP/1.1 200 Tunnel established
    [res_body] => HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Up-CJW9XP4E84DqWjZhI_8-YFgWR47UNNfqGkmM2S5EBf3H5aGOcuwHzLd-4faoKAxd_qgaO5GInDUiJx6uua8JDwj4X0yLamxA--WySFB3ZZxw7YQ
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 12:48:24 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"

Not Found
    [errno] => 0
    [error] =>
)
```

so, is the draft can not edited using a resumable upload?

How can I edit a draft with a large attachment?

Answer (score 0):

when you update draft, it must used put.

like:
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/r6052444812129220058

Comment: I found the answer.